# Reference apex_workspace_apex_users or wwv_flow_fnd_user in a foreign key constraint

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-18c

What I'm trying to do is to extend authorisation upon APEX basic users to use it as conditions of pages rendering. I would like to create additional tables to store some workspace specific info about users. Is it possible to reference `wwv_flow_fnd_user.user_name` or `apex_workspace_apex_users.user_name` as a `foreign key` constraint? If yes, how to? If no, what's the alternative to bind APEX user info with my own additional info on database level?

I've tried:

- `CONSTRAINT FK_USER_NAME FOREIGN KEY (USER_NAME) REFERENCES apex_workspace_apex_users (USER_NAME) ON DELETE CASCADE`
- `CONSTRAINT FK_USER_NAME FOREIGN KEY (USER_NAME) REFERENCES wwv_flow_fnd_user (USER_NAME) ON DELETE CASCADE`
- `CONSTRAINT FK_USER_NAME FOREIGN KEY (USER_NAME) REFERENCES APEX_190100.wwv_flow_fnd_user (USER_NAME) ON DELETE CASCADE`

All of this both as SYSDBA and as an owning schema of an APEX workspace. All I've got so far is a bunch of errors like `insufficient priviliges` and `table or view does not exist`.

Comment: It's not really good practice to reference internal Oracle tables in this way

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Ok. But what's the alternative then?